# Insert to first Null column

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
id | datetime | player1 | player2 | player3 | player4 | player5 | player6 | player7 | player8 | player9 | player10 | player11 | player12 | player13 | player14 | player15 | player16 | player17 | player18 | player19 | player20

id AND datetime IS NOT NULL. playerX IS NULL.
```

I need a query that `INSERT`s value to the selected time and first `NULL` column in that row.

Somethng like:

```
INSERT INTO matches(playerX) VALUES ('player_id') WHERE datetime="2016-1-4 12:00:00";
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: what you need to do is fix your table so it's properly normalized, and then you don't have to worry about finding a "Null" column... this design is **NOT** going to be pleasant to maintain, or build. save yourself a lot of agony and give up on this layout, NOW. and note that since you're inserting a new record, by definition ALL of the fields are null,b ecause they're all empty - the record doesn't exist yet.

Comment: can you please put your schema into your question?  This problem could be a result of your schema not being properly setup.

Comment: I believe the first thing he stated was his schema... I agree with Marc B, this is a schema smell

Comment: Ok, so it would be better to create table with 3 indexes (id, datetime, player) and insert 20 rows of same datetime?

Comment: I guess you could write a stored procedure which selects the row and then has a bunch of `IF` blocks.  Or if this has to be a single `UPDATE` statement then you can write one of the ugliest nested structure of `CASE` statements in history.  Or you could build an actual relational structure and just do a simple `UPDATE` (or `INSERT`) statement.

Comment: @Vergil333: Probably, yes.  What data does a record in this table actually represent?

Comment: @David Players going to sign up for a match. I think I already know what to do. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Vergil333: In that case it sounds like a standard many-to-many table.  You have `Players`, you have `Matches`, what you want is a `PlayerMatches` table which has a FK to `Players` and to `Matches`.  (This is all assuming some details about the rest of the structure of course.  There may be subtle differences in your case that we don't know about.)

Comment: This schema violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The reason you're having so much trouble adding data is because you're going against the grain of how a relational database works. Create a proper association table and this would be trivial.

Comment: You might have a table of matches (match_id,date), a table of players (player_id,name), and a table table that links players to matches (player_id,match_id). Position might be a column in the players table OR the player_match pivot table.